# How to fix discord music bot that stops playing before the song is actually over?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I've coded a simple music bot that has commands like `join`, `play`, `pause`, `resume`, and `leave`. I'm having an issue where I'll run the `play` command with a song, which can be either a youtube link or just the name of a youtube video, and it'll play most of the song, and then it'll randomly stop playing. I'm assuming that it's an issue with the `play` command, though I'm not sure. Another piece of info is that I'm hosting my bot on a web-hosting service called Heroku, but I don't think that's very relevant, as I have all the buildpacks set up on Heroku, and I've had no issues there. Here's the code I'm working with:

```py
import asyncio

import discord
import youtube_dl

from discord.ext import commands

# Suppress noise about console usage from errors
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(description="joins a voice channel")
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None or ctx.author.voice.channel is None:
            return await ctx.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command!')

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            vc = await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
            vc = ctx.voice_client

    @commands.command(description="streams music")
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=f"[{player.title}]({player.url}) [{ctx.author.mention}]")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    @commands.command(description="pauses music")
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Paused ⏸️")
    
    @commands.command(description="resumes music")
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resuming ⏯️")

    @commands.command(description="stops and disconnects the bot from voice")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @play.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
```

Others have been having the same issue and have posted about them on stackoverflow, but no one seems to have responded to those issues. I've checked Github repos and many other websites including stackoverflow, but I've had no luck. I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me out!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is within the FFMPEG executable getting corrupt packets from the webhost, which causes it to terminate.

You can see this by manually setting `loglevel` to `verbose` in discords `FFmpegPCMAudio` class.

Since we'd rather reconnect than terminate the song early, you can change your `ffmpeg_options` to the following:

```
ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
    "before_options": "-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5"
}
```

Here's a complete bot using those parameters: [Lenart12's MusicBot](https://gist.github.com/Lenart12/024222b63db38c65f68b57ae7e623d56#file-music_bot_example-py-L57)