# Discord bot stops playing music at a certain iteration

Tags: python, ubuntu, ffmpeg, discord, pycord

I'm using the following code to play music in a discord voice channel:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

YDL_OPTIONS = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best', 
}

FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {
    'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 
    'options': '-vn'
}

bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def get_source_url(url: str) -> str:
    with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        return ydl.extract_info(url, download=False).get('url')

@bot.slash_command(name='play')
async def __play(ctx, url: str) -> None:
    source = await get_source_url(url)
    vc = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))

    while vc.is_playing() or vc.is_paused():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await vc.disconnect()

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

The principle of operation is as follows:

1. The `/play` command handler receives a `url` argument, in the form of a link to a live stream from YouTube: https://youtu.be/jfKfPfyJRdk *(or any other video)*
2. The link is passed to the `get_source_url` function, which, using the `yt-dlp` library, returns a direct link to the sound from the video
3. The direct link is passed via `discord.FFmpegPCMAudio` to the `ffmpeg` program, which then returns audio bytes for transmission to the discord voice channel via the `vc.play` method

---

### Problem:

Bot is hosted on the virtual hosting server [**aeza**](https://aeza.net/), OS - `Ubuntu Server 22.04`.  I installed the `ffmpeg` version `4.4.2` with the command `sudo apt install ffmpeg`.

On the first day everything worked fine, but the next day the bot began to steadily stop playing music at the same moment in different videos *(this moment is different for each video)*. **Restarting the bot or server did not help.**

**Only reinstalling the operating system helps, but also only for one day.**

### Specific problem:

I checked the execution of every single line of the [`discord.VoiceClient.play`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/_modules/discord/voice_client.html#VoiceClient.play) method, including all methods called internally. It turned out that the bot hangs every time on the same iteration of the cycle of receiving and sending bytes. Namely, on the first line of the [`discord.FFmpegPCMAudio.read`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/_modules/discord/player.html#FFmpegPCMAudio.read) method, that is does not receive data from `ffmpeg` and waits indefinitely.

---

### Source of the problem:

The problem is not with a specific `ffmpeg`:

- I also installed `ffmpeg` on another version `5.1.2` and the problem was repeated on it.

The problem is not `Ubuntu Server`:

- I changed OS `Ubuntu Server` to `Debian 11` and it's the same there

The problem is not in `Linux`:

- When I put the same OS on my virtual machine, everything worked fine with any version of `ffmpeg`.

---

So the problem is on the hosting side?  I asked those.  support to change the server itself and the location of the location.  Changed from Sweden to Germany - the same result.

If the data does not come from `ffmpeg`, then you need to find out what is wrong in the program itself.  When calling, I pass the `-loglevel debug` argument, which shows the most detailed report on the program's operation - all debugging information is displayed, but there are no errors on the "hung" iteration.

**What could be the problem?**

---

**UPD 03.05.2023**: I reinstalled OS Ubuntu Server again and the bot works now. But obviously not for long. Maybe I need to clear some cache?